# Pass value from <select> element C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a checkout page in a C#/.NET project that is configured to pull a single price from a Product. I added a second price option (for single & multi user subscriptions) and allow users to choose between them with a `<select>` element. The part that I am having trouble with is how do I get the selected `<option>` to be passed through to `data-price="@product.Price"` and `product.Price`

```
var selectedPrice = 0.00m;

var totalAmount = Model.Products.Sum(x => x.Price * Model.ProductIDs.Where(productID => productID == x.ID).Count());
var discount = ConfigurationsHelper.Discount;
var finalAmount = totalAmount - discount + ConfigurationsHelper.FlatDeliveryCharges;

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
        {
            i++;

            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@i</th>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.ProductDetails(product.Category.SanitizedName, product.ID)">
                        @product.Name
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="price" class="form-control" id="selectedPrice">
                        <option name="SingleUser" data-id="singlePrice" value="@product.Price.WithCurrency()">Single-User: @product.Price.WithCurrency()</option>
                        <option name="MultiUser" data-id="multiPrice" value="@product.MultiPrice.WithCurrency()">Multi-User: @product.MultiPrice.WithCurrency()</option>
                    </select>

                    <script>
                        $('select').on('change', function () {
                            selectedPrice = this.value;
                        });
                    </script>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control changeQuantity productQuantity" value="@Model.ProductIDs.Where(x => x == product.ID).Count()" data-id="@product.ID" data-price="selectedPrice" min="1" max="100" title="Quantity">
                </td>
                <td>
                    @((selectedPrice * Model.ProductIDs.Where(x => x == product.ID).Count()).WithCurrency())
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="deleteCartProduct btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                <strong>Total</strong>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>
                    @totalAmount.WithCurrency()
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                <strong>Discount</strong>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>
                    @discount.WithCurrency()
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                <strong>Delivery Charges</strong>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>
                    @ConfigurationsHelper.FlatDeliveryCharges.WithCurrency()
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                <strong>Final Amount</strong>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>
                    @finalAmount.WithCurrency()
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right">
                <div class="btn-group btn-block" role="group">
                    <button data-href="@Url.Checkout()" class="update-cart-links btn btn-primary" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-sync-alt mr-1"></i>
                        Update
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="nextDeliveryTab" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-1"></i>
                        Next
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

}

Comment: The selection from the drop down is happening client-side, so you have to process it either client side, or pass through the option and process it server side. I think what you are trying to do is put in some code and have it update the markup dynamically as the user interacts. You can't do that without javascript. If you are going to process it client side, you would need to use javascript to update the values in the DOM. If you are doing it server side, you would pass the option through to your controller, probably via ajax, and then respond with the data for use client side

Comment: Ok, so I initialized `var selectedPrice = 0.00m` and wrote this script `<script>
                            $('select').on('change', function () {
                                selectedPrice = this.value;
                                alert(selectedPrice);
                            });
                        </script>`                This alerts the price I was looking for, but when I place this variable in the `data-price` parameter it just shows as 0.00

Comment: Please update your question to show how you 'place this variable in the `data-price` parameter'

Comment: @Jonathan i updated the code